# Repeating an image texture

Tags: texturing, image

I am fairly new to Blender and I am wondering how you would go about filling a space with a texture, which is repeating over and over.

For example if you are modelling a kitchen and have a texture of a floor tile, but obviously the kitchen has more tiles than just one. How do you tell Blender to repeat image textures to be able to fill surfaces which are from the same material?

Comment: Note that repeating textures is usually not a good thing, because people will be able to see the patterns causing your render to be unrealistic.

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have this tile picture:

[image]

You can either scale up the floor UV map in the UV Editor:

[image]

... or plug a *Mapping* node in the *Image Texture* node and play with the scale values:

[image]

In the latest versions of Blender you can plug an *Input > Value* into the *Scale* input of the *Mapping* node to make it easier to tweak:

[image]